# Backbone JS not processing my model

Tags: backbone.js

I cannot get my backbone.js app to take in my model. Anybody have any idea what's going on?

The site is http://www.sheetmusicondemand.net/backbone2.html

The code is there and here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Backbone Demo</h1>
            <hr />
            <div class="page">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/template" id="song-list-template">
            <h3>Songs</h3>
            <% _.each(songs, function(song) { console.log song.toJSON();%>

            <h4>Title: <%= song.title %></h4>
            <% } %>
        </script>

        <!--    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/backbone.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
                options.url = 'http://www.onlinesheetmusic.com/api2/' + options.url;
            });

            function htmlEncode(value) {
                return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
            }

            function htmlDecode(value) {
                return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
            }

            $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
                var o = {};
                var a = this.serializeArray();
                $.each(a, function () {
                    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                        if (!o[this.name].push) {
                            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                        }
                        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                    } else {
                        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                    }
                });
                return o;
            };

            var Songs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                url: '/product'
            });

            var Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
                urlRoot: '/product'
            });

            var SongList = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: '.page',
                render: function () {
                    var that = this;
                    var songs = new Songs();
                    songs.fetch({
                        success: function (songs) {
                            console.log($(songs).serializeObject());
                            var template = _.template($('#song-list-template').html(), { songs: songs.models });
                            that.$el.html(template);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes: {
                    '': 'home'
                }
            });

            var songList = new SongList();

            var router = new Router();
            router.on('route:home', function () {
                songList.render();
            });

            Backbone.history.start();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It keeps returning Uncaught Syntax Error and the object is empty. All I am trying to do is get it to process the data returned. Why is it not printing the songs titles? What I am missing?

Comment: Can you declare `Song` model before the collection, and specify `model : Song` just as [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) inside the `Songs` collection and give it a try ?

Comment: I figured it out. I am just dumb and forgot to close my each in the template. I left it as } without the ); now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
<% _.each(songs, function(song) { console.log song.toJSON();%>
```

should be:

```
<% _.each(songs, function(song) { console.log(song.toJSON());%>
```

Comment: That did fix the initial issue, but I am still having a problem with the data not working for some reason. I have updated the code on the site and you will now see I am getting the error:   `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; underscore.js:997`

Comment: Generally speaking, if you get an answer at Stack Overflow and need to ask a new question, it's better to start a new question (with just the info that's relevant to the new question) rather than edit your question to turn it in to a new question.